# Markdown File Unable To Process Unordered Lists Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, graphql, markdown, gatsby

I'm using Gatsby to build a new website. I'd like to render some markdown files for a blog, but it doesn't seem to be able to process the lists/unordered lists based on the markdown syntax. For instance, this is the syntax:

```
* Purple dots are points on the graph, each point has an x and y coordinate. These are your observed values

* Blue line is the prediction line, covering the estimated values of the model

* The red line between each purple point and the prediction line are the errors. Each error is the distance from the point to its predicted point.
```

This is the output:

[image: Unordered List]

I also found that it's not possible to use `#` for the headers. For instance, here's my post description and title:

```
_Making Use of the scipy.optimize Library in Python to Minimize Error_

## Revision
```

Output:

[image: Title and description]

I'm not sure what I need to change within Gatsby to render the markdown correctly?

Comment: How are you rendering it? Do you have a live site?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is rendering properly the markdown file, however, you haven't added any style to make them look like an unordered list or as a header.

Just add your stylesheet file:

```
import './yourStyles.scss'
```

In `yourStyles.scss`:

```
h1 {
   font-size: 3rem;
   color: red;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: default; // change it by desired value
}
```